# Google Analytics custom variables not showing up

Tags: google-analytics

I have been running this code for some time now on all pages.  This custom variable has never shown up.

Sorry to ask this again, I don't see another post that solves my case.  This has to be the simplest case in the world, this is the same code with only the UA changed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'User', 'jc', 3]);
    (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I did not modify the (function()...) .. Do you see the problem?  I'm using slot 1 with the page level (3) scope.  The same code appears on each page for a given user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_setCustomVar` does not trigger a request to GA. `_trackPageview` does. You have to move the `_setCustomVar` above the `_trackPageview`.

Comment: I am having the same problem, the custom variable is not showing up in GA, how long should it take before the custom variables show up?